# RegEx for extracting the last combination of numbers from a paragraph

Tags: node.js, regex, numbers, readline, regex-lookarounds

RegEx for extracting the last combination of numbers from a paragraph

**E.g.**:

> “My ID is 112243 and my phone number is 0987654321. Thanks you.”

So I want to extract the phone number here which is the last combo of digits.

Comment: Is your ID always going to be the same amount of numbers?  You could try to get a regex based on the phone number pattern to extract it.

Comment: What did you do so far? What issue are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
\d+(?=\D*$)
```

Here, `\d+` selects one or more number and this positive lookahead `(?=\D*$)` ensures that if at all anything is present further ahead before end of string then it is not a digit (by using `\D*` before `$`).

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ItMJQt/2/)**

JS Code demo,

```js
const s = 'My ID is 112243 and my phone number is 0987654321. Thanks you.'

console.log(s.match(/\d+(?=\D*$)/))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = "My ID is 112243 and my phone number is 0987654321. Thanks you";
var numbers = string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
console.log(numbers);
```

It will give you all combo of numbers in an array. You can choose which one you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple regex like [`^.*\b(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Yjbiq0/1/)

```js
var str = 'My ID is 112243 and my phone number is 0987654321. Thanks you';
var num = str.match(/^.*\b(\d+)/)[1];
console.log(num);
```

- [Greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/5527985) `.*` will consume anything before the last `\b` *word boundary* followed by `\d+` digits.
- The parenthesis around `\d+` will [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the stuff inside to `[1]`
- If input is a multiline string, use such as [`[\s\S]*` instead of `.*`](https://regex101.com/r/Yjbiq0/2) to skip over newlines.

Comment: Thanks. Working and best for multiline document. This is exact what I needed.